# TFS story disappearing from board when adding child stories to it

Tags: tfs, storyboard, user-stories

My team has a User Story created in our backlog to track all information related to an upcoming release. I like to make the stories included in the release children of the main story. However, whenever I add a child story to the main story, the main story no longer appears in the Board view on TFS. It does still appear in the Backlog view though.

Why is this? Any way to change this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The Board view will only show the leaf item of each level. So if you have:

```
story 1  
+- story 2
+- story 3
```

Only story 2 and 3 will show up on any boards. The exact reason for the choice I don't exactly remember, but I believe it has to do with the roll-up of estimate and value as well as deciding on the order.

There is no way to change this behaviour,

A better solution would be to link them as "Related" instead of "parent/child". or to create the release at the Feature level and associate all items to the feature instead of an item from the same level.